# ASP.NET 5 not running in development mode

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-core

I have updated my ASP.NET 5 project to beta 8, and we are now supposed to the following web command

```
"commands": {
    "web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel"
},
```

Now i have updated my project with the environment variables.

[image]

This has also updated my launchSettings.json file, as so

```
{
  "profiles": {
    "web": {
      "commandName": "web",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNET_ENV": "Development"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But for some reason, every time I run the command `dnx web` it says that the hosting environment is Production.  Why is it not starting in development mode?

[image]

Answer (score 13):

The settings in `launchSettings.json` are only used by VS. If you run from a console, you have to set that environment variable manually.

CMD:

```
set ASPNET_ENV=Development
dnx web
```

PS:

```
$env:ASPNET_ENV=Development
dnx web
```

Comment: this is also working: 

dnx web ASPNET_ENV=Development

Comment: set ASPNET_ENV=Development does not work.  dnx web ASPNET_DEV=Development does work though.

Comment: How to set this environment variable during the build process? I am guessing it will need to be updated to "staging" and "production" as and when it is deployed to these environments

Answer (score 1):

Adding to @Victor Hurdugaci answer, you could also avoid "messing" with current environment by passing needed variables on command line.

Inside `project.json` file, say that you have a `web-dev` command specific for development environment:

```js
"commands": {
  "web-dev": "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel 
    --ASPNET_ENV Development --Hosting:Environment Development 
    --config hosting.Development.json",
},
```

where you can see how both `ASPNET_ENV`, `Hosting:Environment` are set, as well as invoking a specific `hosting.json` configuration.
**NOTE:** command is split on several lines just for readability, join again before actually pasting in JSON file.

Answer (score 0):

The command: `set ASPNET_ENV=Development` is now obsolete instead you can use CMD:

```
set ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
```