# Is launchSettings.json used when running ASP.NET 5 apps from the command line on Mac?

Tags: c#, configuration, environment-variables, asp.net-core

I am developing an ASP.NET 5 Web API app using Visual Studio code on Mac. I manually modified my `Properties/launchSettings.json` file to set environment to `Staging` for all profiles using `ASPNET_ENV` environment variable:
[image]

However, when I run `dnx web` in Mac terminal to start the app, I still get `Production` environment:
[image]

Can I use `launchSettings.json` to specify environment variables (and, thus, environment types) if I use Visual Studio Code on Mac? Or is it specific to full Visual Studio?

ASP.NET 5 docs [suggest](http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/environments.html) that `launchSettings.json` can be used to inject environment variables. However, [this SO discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28258227/how-to-set-ihostingenvironment-environmentname-in-vnext-application) suggests passing them through commands.

Comment: According to this answer, launchSettings.json is only used by VS:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/33374841/409259

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**LaunchSettings.json is strictly a VS concept.** In other cases, you will have to configure environment variables as commands below:

**For standard command line run, use:**

```
set ASPNET_ENV=Development

dnx web
```

**For powershell, use:**

```
$env:ASPNET_ENV='Development'

dnx web
```

**Shorter version:** `dnx web ASPNET_ENV=Development`

Comment: The above answer is correct but the OP did state he was using a mac. In order to set the environment to development on a mac, use the following from the terminal: 

    export ASPNET_ENV=Development

Comment: When trying to set that within `project.json` `commands` section instead, you get something like: `"commands": { "web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel --config hosting.Development.json --ASPNET_ENV Development" }`. Right?

Comment: The environment variable 'ASPNET_ENV' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT' (.NET Core RC2)

Answer (score 5):

On a Mac, using Terminal, type:

```
export ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development && dotnet run
```

**Requirements:**

- .NET Core (rc2)
- [.NET command line interface](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core#macosx)

Comment: Or in Windows set ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development && dotnet run -> this work for me

Answer (score 0):

Adding to @Chrysalis answer, you could also avoid "messing" with current environment by passing needed variables on command line.

Inside `project.json` file, say that you have a `web-dev` command specific for development environment:

```js
"commands": {
  "web-dev": "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel 
    --ASPNET_ENV Development --Hosting:Environment Development 
    --config hosting.Development.json",
},
```

where you can see how both `ASPNET_ENV`, `Hosting:Environment` are set, as well as invoking a specific `hosting.json` configuration.
**NOTE:** command is split on several lines just for readability, join again before actually pasting in JSON file.