# What's the difference between ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT in launchsettings.json and run configuration

Tags: azure, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

What's the difference between setting the `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` environment variable in `launchsettings.json`

```
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:55556/",
      "sslPort": 0
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "Departures": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      },
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:5001/"
    }
  }
}
```

and run configuration?

[image]

Neither seems to have an affect on what is actually used by the application.

This posting ([Is launchSettings.json used when running ASP.NET 5 apps from the command line on Mac?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34553048/is-launchsettings-json-used-when-running-asp-net-5-apps-from-the-command-line-on#34555423)) suggests that the proper way to set the `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` value is via the command line.

Questions:

- what is the 'right' way to set the `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` value?
- can this value be displayed in a Razor view (`Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.IHostingEnvironment.EnvironmentName`)?
- Can I use the `Application settings` section of my App's blade to properly set the `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` value?

[image]

Comment: Not sure about your first two questions as I'm not going to comment on doing this with a Mac. With regards to your Azure App Service, the config looks OK so it should be using the Environment variable that you have set.

Comment: This doc might help - [Working with multiple environments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments)